# connect to mysql database in NiFi

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, apache-nifi

[image]I have set up nifi on the Kubernetes cluster under nifi namespace.
My service is up and running now I need to connect to one of my databases for which I'm using DBCPConnectionPool.
I'm getting the following error

```
StandardControllerServiceNode[service=DBCPConnectionPool[id=c91863c8-018c-1000-4807-b1f99934eaaf], name=DBCPConnectionPool, active=true] Failed to invoke @OnEnabled method: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Driver class cdata.jdbc.mysql.MySQLDriver
 is not found
```

Comment: you have to put library with jdbc driver under nifi/lib folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Swathi DA

The DataBase Connection Pool allows you to provide the path to the driver.  Database Driver Location(s).   Download the appropriate driver and deliver that to the same location in all nifi nodes.  Make sure the file(s) are owned and permissioned to nifi user.   Disable, configure the location, then re-enable and retest the processor referencing the DBCP.